# Swiftkey ignores TextInputEditText flag InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS - doesn't capitalize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, swift-keyboard

I have a simple TextInputLayout. TextInputEditText which is inside TextInputLayout has two InputType flags -

```
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
```

and

```
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS
```

These flags are set programmatically. It should disable suggestions and capitalize each single word which you write. It works without problem on default Android keyboard.
Unfortunately, if you use Swift Keyboard instead it ignores the second flag (it doesn't automatically capitalize the first letter of each word. 
I don't have any experience with 3rd party soft keyboards. Does anybody have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I found out that SwiftKey ignores all InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_XXX if you set them programmatically. I tried to set them in XML and it worked fine. However, it still isn't the best solution because sometimes it is necessary to set it programmatically. I somebody find some better solution please leave a comment :)